# Is there a Firebase SDK available for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on a module in python that sends Push Notifications using firebase-cloud-messaging. Is there any sdk in python that I can use for the same.

I did search on google and found a java sdk, however couldn't find any sources for python.

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing, below is steps you may take to go ahead with it:

Install https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/ from PyPi

Use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging module to achieve desired behaviour of your application

Comment: Many thanks. I referred the link but couldn't find any way to create an instance of firebase_admin by providing FCM Server key or other details. Any hints on how can I get this done?